# How to send multiple UserState with BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

How can I send with BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress more than one UserState?

For example:

```
progressbar.Value = e.UserState as double;
```

This one will be for the ProgessBar

```
lblpercent.Content = e.UserState as string;
```

This one will be for the Label

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the progress to the `percentProgress` Argument

```
worker.ReportProgress(55,"test");

progressbar.Value = e.PercentProgress / 100.0 * progressbar.MaxValue;
lblpercent.Content = e.UserState.ToString();
```

Or pass a class/struct via the `userState`

```
class MyUserState
{
    public double Value {get;set;}
    public string Content {get;set;}
}

worker.ReportProgress(55,new MyUserState { Value = 23.7, Content = "Working ..."});

MyUserState state = e.UserState as MyUserState;
progressbar.Value = state.Value;
lblpercent.Content = state.Content;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did like this into `backgroundWorker1_DoWork`:

```
string [] workerResult = new string[3];
workerResult[0] = total.ToString();
orkerResult[1] = "Files Copied: " + i + "/" + filecount;
workerResult[2] = "Size Copied: " + totalmb + "/" + totalsize + " MB";
```

and into `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` I put:

```
string[] results = (string[])e.UserState;
progressbar.Value = double.Parse(results[0]);
lblcopiedfiles.Content = results[1];
lblsizecopied.Content = results[2];
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: That works too, but is it really any better than the previous answer? Also, nitpicking, formatting strings and such are tasks for the Gui (_ProgressChanged), not for DoWork.